# Popup window showing error that another program is using this file

Tags: popupwindow

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA721.png)

After every 5 mins, I am getting this message and when I am going to the location but it's not there. Is it a virus that is there in my computer?
What should I do now?

Comment: The `Program Files` folder can be named differently on a non-English systems, something like `Programoj`. It could be that an application was installed in two versions or whatever. Your image is not really informative. Check for a virus is indeed something I would do first. If you already have an active virus scanner, also that could be the problem (though not probable). This forum is more for programming errors I think.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some broken software on your computer. Try remembering which programs you added recently that might have lead to this issue. If you want to be save, run a antivirus scan. Joop Eggen is right, this is a forum for programming questions. I think there are others where there are people who know more about windows than I do. I still hope my answer helped.